# Java error while running maxent in biomod2

Tags: java, r, maxent, biomod2

I am running maxent from R, in the package biomod2 and the following error appeared. I do not come from a technical background and wasn't sure why is this error happening. Is it a memory problem or someone said the java path is not set. But I followed the instructions to set maxent to run in R and also downloaded Java Platform, Standard Edition Development Kit and set a path for it as explained in this pdf: http://modata.ceoe.udel.edu/dev/dhaulsee/class_rcode/r_pkgmanuals/MAXENT4R_directions.pdf

I would be really grateful if you could help me understand this problem and any solution to it.

Thanks a lot

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'java' had status 1 
2: running command 'java -mx512m -jar E:\bioclim_2.5min\model/maxent.jar environmentallayers
="rainfed/models/1432733200/m_47203134/Back_swd.csv" 
samplesfile="rainfed/models/1432733200/m_47203134/Sp_swd.csv" 
projectionlayers="rainfed/models/1432733200/m_47203134/Predictions/Pred_swd.csv" 
outputdirectory="rainfed/models/1432733200/rainfed_PA1_Full_MAXENT_outputs" 
outputformat=logistic  redoifexists visible=FALSE linear=TRUE quadratic=TRUE 
product=TRUE threshold=TRUE hinge=TRUE lq2lqptthreshold=80 l2lqthreshold=10 
hingethreshold=15 beta_threshold=-1 beta_categorical=-1 beta_lqp=-1 
beta_hinge=-1 defaultprevalence=0.5 autorun nowarnings notooltips 
noaddsamplestobackground' had status 1 
3: In file(file, "rt") :
 cannot open file 'rainfed/models/1432733200/rainfed_PA1_Full_MAXENT_outputs/rainfed_PA1_
Full_Pred_swd.csv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I've just had exactly this problem. For me, all other models within `biomod2` are working, and MaxEnt runs okay from `dismo`. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just manage to solve this problem - it is a problem with the file path specified. For me, I had a space in one of the folder names which was not accepted in the path to the `maxent.jar` file. From looking at your error, it looks like it might be the two backslashes.

```
E:\bioclim_2.5min\model/maxent.jar
```

should probably read

```
E:/bioclim_2.5min/model/maxent.jar
```

Comment: I have the same issue here, @Andrew ... did someone managed to deal with this problem? I don't have space in folder names... and I can't fix the backlashes... no matter which "lashes" I use, it automatically records backlashes..